# C++ Casting types (SLODWORD and long)

Tags: c++, types, casting

Consider variable as float.

What is the difference between `*((long*)&variable)` and `(long)variable`?

Isn't the same thing?

Why my program output different results for each one?

Comment: The first is a reference - the second a (temporary) value (lvalue vs. rvalue)

Comment: What is the actual type of `variable`?

Comment: The 1st version interprets the 4 bytes of the float value as though they were long.  Producing a wildly different value, you only crash the program when *long* is a 64-bit type if you are lucky.  The 2nd version is a proper conversion of the float value, producing a wildly different value only if the float value is out of range.  These are C casts, check your favorite C++ language book for the difference between reinterpret_cast vs static_cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is a *reinterpretation* of the bits stored at `&variable` as if they were representing a long, whereas the second performs a *conversion* of `variable`'s value (what the bits "actually" represent) to a suitable `long` value.

Answer (score 0):

The former works with the variable as if it was stored in the memory as a `long` even when it was not. The latter converts the variable to `long`.